# Getting an element by variable class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must be overlooking something very simple here. But why doesn't my class selector work here? The classes don't toggle while I think I am targeting the right element?

```js
$(".heart").click(function(){
  heartelementid = $(this).data( "elementid" );
  loadurl = "/addlove?id=" + $(this).data( "elementid" )
  heartobject = "heart" + $(this).data( "elementid" )
  $("#div").load(loadurl, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if (statusTxt == "success") {
      console.log("success");
      $('svg.'+heartobject).toggleClass("d-none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="heart" href="#" data-elementid="1234">
  <svg class="heart1234" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" ...></path></svg>
  <svg class="heart1234 d-none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"...></path></svg>
</a>
```

Comment: ...or `statusTxt == "success"` doesn't work.. The selector seems to be fine, check callback function/add error handler

Comment: That one did work. It looks like it didn't work because the class was on an svg. It works if I wrap a div with that class around it…

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a div around the svg solved the problem.